# $(find) not working consistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have a search box on a website that uses an AJAX extender with a webservice.
It works perfectly on the home page.
[http://www.as-technology.co.uk](https://www.as-technology.co.uk).

I have the same control on a subsection page at
[https://www.as-technology.co.uk/toner-cartridges/printer/brother](https://www.as-technology.co.uk/toner-cartridges/printer/brother?s=default_tonercartridgeslist)

This is the exact same control, but the page is one level lower in the file hierarchy(not in the root folder but a sub folder).

I have narrowed down the problem to do with the $(find) javascript function as in the second webpage it can't find the AJAX extender called "dp1". In the first page example(default page) it does.

The javascript function called UpdateControl

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function UpdateControl(value) {
    var behavior = $find('dp1');
    if (behavior) {
        behavior.populate(value);
    }
    return false;
}
function ClearSearch() {
    var lbl = $(this).find('lblSearchResults');
    lbl.value = "";
    return false;
}
```

On the second page the var "behaviour" is null and so the populate doesn't work.

The control's code is this.

```
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
    CodeFile="SearchBoxWithService.ascx.cs" 
    Inherits="MB.ASTechnology.UI.Controls.SearchBoxWithService" %>
    <%@ Import Namespace="MB.ASTechnology.UI" %>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function UpdateControl(value) {
        var behavior = $find('dp1');
        if (behavior) {
            behavior.populate(value);
        }
        return false;
    }
    function ClearSearch() {
        var lbl = $find('lblSearchResults');
        lbl.value = "";
        return false;
    }
     </script>

    <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btnGetHtml" 
    style="float:left;" >


    <div class="input-append">
        <input class="span2" id="txtGetHtml" type="text"  placeholder="Brand & printer model or cartridge code" style="width: 250px;height:35px;"  />
        <asp:Button  CssClass="btn btn-primary" ID="btnGetHtml" UseSubmitBehavior="true"  runat="server" OnClientClick="return UpdateControl(txtGetHtml.value)" Text="Search" />
        <asp:Button  CssClass="btn btn-default" ID="btnClearSearch" UseSubmitBehavior="true"  runat="server" OnClientClick="return ClearSearch" Text="Clear" />
    </div>

    <asp:Button  CssClass="btn" ID="Button1" UseSubmitBehavior="true"  runat="server"  Text="Search" visible="false"/> 
</asp:Panel>
<asp:Label ID="lblSearchResults" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<ajaxToolkit:DynamicPopulateExtender ID="dp1" runat="server" BehaviorID="dp1"
    TargetControlID="lblSearchResults" ServicePath="~/TextSearchService.asmx" ServiceMethod="DynamicPopulateMethod"
    ClearContentsDuringUpdate="true" PopulateTriggerControlID="Button1">
</ajaxToolkit:DynamicPopulateExtender>
```

Comment: What is the logic in the `$find()` function? Also, what is `$(this)` in the first `ClearSearch()` snippet?

Comment: shouldn't it be `var lbl = $(this).find('#lblSearchResults');` ?

Comment: Rory the logic is to pass value to the dynamicPopulateExtender. I have changed each to be $(this).find('#dp1') and for the second function $(this).find('#lblSearchREsults') . For the first function UpdateControl it generates an error "Uncaught TypeError: behavior.populate is not a function"

Answer (score 0):

I used a slideshow extender and it worked basically like this:

```
$find('behaviorID')._contextKey = value;
```

I think most extenders work the same, so it would be something like:

```
function UpdateControl(value) {
    var behavior = $find('dp1');
    if (behavior) {
        behavior._contextKey = value;
    }
    return false;
}
```

hth.

Comment: Or maybe `behavior._populateTriggerControlID`?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. I failed to have the ajax toolscriptmanager on the page that was not working. Instead I had an ordinary asp scriptmanager. I then put line back to $find('dp1') and it worked.